# C# HttpClient GetAsync throwing exception An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

See the below code which is not written by me. When this code run with .Net v4.7.2 with VS2019 then it is working fine but when I am running the same code with VS2013 with .Net v4.5.2 then getting exception. The error message is

> An error occurred while sending the request.

What to change in the below code as a result it should work fine with .Net v4.5.2?

When this line encounter then exception thrown: `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)`.

How to make the code compatible with .net v4.5.2?

Here is full code:

```cs
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private static async Task<T> GetJsonPageAsync<T>(string url)
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(text);
    }
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dynamic newsList = await GetJsonPageAsync<dynamic>("https://www.wsj.com/news/types/newsplus?id={%22query%22:%22type:=\\%22NewsPlus\\%22%22,%22db%22:%22wsjie,blog,interactivemedia%22}&type=search_collection");
        List<Task<dynamic>> tasks = new List<Task<dynamic>>();
        foreach (dynamic item in newsList.collection)
        {
            string strUrl = "https://www.wsj.com/news/types/newsplus?id=" + item.id + "&type=article";
            tasks.Add(GetJsonPageAsync<dynamic>(strUrl));

            //tasks.Add(GetJsonPageAsync<dynamic>($"https://www.wsj.com/news/types/newsplus?id={item.id}&type=article"));
        }

        dynamic[] newsDataList = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        foreach (dynamic newItem in newsDataList)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(newItem.data.headline);
            //Console.WriteLine(newItem.data.url);

            txtData.Text += newItem.data.headline + System.Environment.NewLine;
            txtData.Text += new string('-', 200) +System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

### Fixed ISSUE

I just add this line before **client.GetAsync** and problem solved. my code started to work.

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: @GSerg problem solved. thanks for the link. i update my post.

Comment: Cherk an updated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62853341/12888024) `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

Comment: @aepot your code i last day tried which works fine in VS2019 but fail when run with VS2013.

Comment: I know, I've updated it, already. Read my above comment again please, carefully.